# Freemarker - if I return -1 from TemplateLoader.getLastModified what happens?

Tags: freemarker

If I return -1 from TemplateLoader.getLastModified what happens? Is the cache entry always used, ie the template is never reloaded, or is the cache entry never used, ie the template is always reloaded?

If I want to return something other than -1, eg the value of "now" in order to force the template to always be reloaded, what should the return value be? Seconds since epoch? Milliseconds since epoch? Anything I like because all it does is compare successive values?

I can't find clarity on either point in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the Java convention, it meant to be milliseconds since the epoch (like `System.currentTimeMillis()`), although what matters is only if it changes. In case you don't have a modification time, the standard dummy value to return is `-1`, and as far as you keep returning `-1`, FreeMarker will assume that the template hasn't changed, and so it will not reload it (assuming it wasn't evicted from the cache for other reasons).

Comment: Ta - those answers coincide with my guesses, I should probably have tried guessing a little harder before the code went into production.

Comment: I have added these to the JavaDoc of the next version (not released yet).

Comment: Great! Thanks!!